# Error con routeando con namespace en Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema...estoy utilizando laravel 5.3 y quiero agrupar los controladores por Namespaces para tener ordenado, pero no me funciona si sigo la docu de laravel 5.3...seguramente algo me falta setear en algun lado.

archivo routes/web.php:

```
    Route::group(['namespace' =>'Params'], function()
    {
        Route::get('ooss', 'OossController@index');
    });
```

archivo app/Http/Controllers/Params/OossController.php:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class OossController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            return 'Correcto!';
        }
    }
```

Y no me funciona. Tambien probé cambiando la primer linea del archivo OossController por "namespace App\Http\Controllers\Params;" y nada.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el error que te devuelve?

Comment: El error es: Class App\Http\Controllers\Params\OosController does not exist

Comment: Si es así, te falta una 's' en el nombre de la clase y dejar el namespace como 'App\Http\Controllers\Params'

Comment: @kerunaru fue un error de tipeo en el comentario...el mensaje de error es Class App\Http\Controllers\Params\OossController does not exist

Comment: No habrás cambiado tu namespace por defecto de "App" a cualquier otra cosa, ¿no?

Comment: No he tocado ningun archivo que no sean los mencionados arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprueba si tus archivos estan asi, estoy usando la version v5.3.26 de laravel y funciona bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias!. Mi error es que, cuando agregaba "namespace App\Http\Controller\Params" me faltaba agregar el "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller". Muchas Gracias!